# How to create translation ready theme WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am in search of translating my theme like we usually see themes in which content is shown like `_e('some text', 'textdomain');`
I tried that with poedit software but failed. I am totally unable to achieve that while I have been through these steps :( https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/internationalizing-localizing-wordpress-theme/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/translating-your-theme--wp-25014
still failed though they provided all info, can any one guide my in full detail or any easy way to achieve that ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in poedit software ?
Open poedit tool and go to `File > New Catalog`
Then provide your desired info  (project related info like name etc)
[image]

Then here is the info for your path in your project catalog:

[image]

and here is your keywords (keywords are those which you want to translate).

[image]

when all done now you are ok to save your project but here is note now:

Note: I have created a `languages` folder inside theme directory. It means all above info is valid if you are placing your `.po` file inside languages folder.

So, once you click on ok button, just save your file with `theme` name and you are ready to go.

Note2: In my above example I used `theme` as just for `example purposes` you can use what ever your project name is or what ever you want.

Now, come to usage.

Inside any of your theme file like index.php or any other page which ever you want to use you will use in this way.

```
<?php _e('here is simple word', 'theme'); echo __('another word', 'theme');>
```

this above line is for example purposes you can use what ever you want like in real world it will be some thing like:

```
<h1>Search Results:</h1>
```

it will become some thing like

```
<h1><?php _e('Search Results', 'theme'); ?></h1>
```

In this way it will become translation ready and can be translated to any theme as you want .... !!!

If you find any issue in this then you may solve your issue by placing below code inside your `functions.php` file.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup');
function my_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain('theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
```

That's complete A to Z details for creating your theme translation ready using poedit software.

Note3: When ever you add any new code like `_e('my name is kami', 'theme');` you can check your string inside poedit software by clicking on update catalog button and your string will show up there. Then you can translate it accordingly by pressing `Alt + c`
If you still have any confusion let me know ?

Comment: thank you very much for in depth answer, it really works great :)

Answer (score 0):

It’s very well explained in the WordPress developer handbook. You should read it: it is very well written, brief and explains *everything*.

Bookmark this for themes:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/

And this for plugins:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/

I link instead of quoting, because it’s a living document. These are just localization chapters, but the entire handbooks are well worth the time spent reading them.

The other answer here is missing some of the requirements (‘Text Domain’ and ‘Domain Path’ headers) and is incorrect about some requirements (domain *must* be slug).

Comment: Sir, can you elaborate what you mean by domain must by slug ?

Comment: thanks for that and can you explain an answer to my this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329164/how-radium-one-click-import-can-be-extended-to-import-from-different-demos